# Best way creating a mobile app and connecting with a database

Tags: c#, android, mobile, server

I'm trying to find the best way creating a mobile application, and connected with a cloud database(or server).
So my first question is: Is it good practice to communicate directly into a database from a mobile app?

If yes, which is the best database for this work? Azure? Oracle? Firebase...?

If no,  which is the best service to communicate first? And which protocol?

What is the most recommended way? Does it matter what os(windows?mac?) my server will use?

Comment: What about a Restful api?

Comment: What framework will you be using? Xamarin.Forms? Xamarin.Android?

Comment: Yes i will use xamarin. And i prefer to connect on  a windows server,using Sql server database. I don't if it is good solution, but i know very good sql server and c#

Comment: You can use any Databases you want, create a RESTfull api inbetween and consume the apis from your mobile app

Comment: @Dim you could create a Restful Api with ASP.Net and handle your database with this. This makes it easy because firing queries from your apps is not the best thing if you are not using a localdb on the phone. You can create realatively quick a api with the basic CRUD (Create Read Upade Delete) operations, the only tricky thing is the authentication between the service and the apps.

Comment: So, it doesn't matter database which i will use, but it is recommended to use a restfull api inbetween... If i will create an exe using http listener on server and http client on mobile? Can't it be risky or it is no recommended ?

Comment: @Dim the risky thing is to send your auth over the web without https.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. But only one last question.I dont understand rest api stucture. It works like a browser?  Example i will have a browser always opened on my server which it will handle communication between mobile and database?

Comment: @Dim you need to host it on your server, its basicially like a website. With connecting like yourdomain.com/api/get/users?id=1 you would get a user with the id 1. So you need a webserver (IIS on windows) to host your website.

Comment: but as @riazosama said firebase would be a great option too! It handles the access restriction etc. Just keep your requests as low as possible.

Comment: Can i use http server for this work? Creating an *.exe or windows service on my windows server? Cause i know how to use it very well. Or it is difficult to handle it with multiple queries?

Comment: What do you exaclty mean by "http server"? A webserver? Yes! I dont really get what you mean by *.exe... For a Restful Api you need a webserver since it is like a website.

Comment: I made an *.exe using c# and http listener which it listens in a specific port. Is it the same like a webserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach if to build a REST API to communicate with your server. But if you don't want to do that, you should look for Firebase. Firebase is one of the best platform to build mobile and web application really fast. It provide you with Authentication, Real-Time Database, Storage, hosting crash reports and many more. Using firebase, you can set security rules on who can write to you database thus it eliminate the risk of unauthorized access to the database. 
Also keep in mind that, if you use firebase, you should structure your db in such a way that the number of read and write requests are as minimal as possible, as firebase could be a bit expensive if not used properly.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to build a api in between. Doing queries in your app is kinda risky.

You could use a nodejs framework for this e.g. Sails.js or Express.js

Answer (score 0):

For a cloud database, Firebase is a very easy to implement and work with Database. There are plenty of information resources about the setup and work process.

Comment: Is it good practice connecting directly to it? Or should i use an web service?